# Gitlab EE: Inherited start and end date for epic are not updated

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ee

I'm posting this bug here, with a workaround solution. I tried to upload it to Gitlab's Gitlab, but my issue can't be submitted because it is detected as a spam, for whatever reason. Maybe if a Gitlab's staff member sees it here they can forward.

Easy to reproduce :

- Create a milestone M going from days DayStart to DayEnd
- Create an epic E1
- Create N issues in a project P in a subgroup of the group holding epic
- Associate these N issues to epic E1 and milestone M. What happens here is that E1 inherits its start and end date from M.
- Create an Epic E2 child of epic E1
- Go to project's P issues list and group-edit them associating them all to epic E2

This is where the bug happens: E2's start and end date are not inherited from the issues, inheritance for both is set to "None", while they should be inherited from issues milestone M.

To sum up, updating the epic of multiple issues seems not to trigger milestone start and end date inheritance update.

This was tested on GitLab Enterprise Edition 14.4.0-ee, dockerized version, freshly installed.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround while waiting for a fix is to take any issue linked to the non-updated epic, unbind it to its milestone and re-binding it again, then the epic start and end date inheritance get updated.